# Connect Next js app to azure app insights using open telemtry through the package - @vercel/otel

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

I encountered the Next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation) that mentions using the package "@vercel/otel" for OpenTelemetry configuration. I followed the instructions and successfully set it up on the client side. However, it appears that there's a need for an OpenTelemetry collector backend to collect the data, and I need to use Azure Application Insights as a collector. When I checked the marketplace, I couldn't find Azure Application Insights listed as a collector [here](https://vercel.com/docs/observability/otel-overview/quickstart), but I did find other options like Datadog.

My question is, how can I connect my Next.js app to Azure Application Insights using OpenTelemetry, and is it possible to log data using the "@vercel/otel" package for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- These are the dependencies which I have installed.

[image]

Check this official page [Optimizing: OpenTelemetry | Next.js (nextjs.org)](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/open-telemetry).

**Enable Experimental OpenTelemetry**:

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    instrumentationHook: true,
  },
}
```

- This is my application **instrumentation.ts:**

```
import { registerOTel } from '@vercel/otel';
import { AzureMonitorTraceExporter } from '@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter';
import { NodeTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/node';
import { SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/tracing';

export function register() {
  // Register OpenTelemetry with a custom service name (e.g., 'next-app')
  registerOTel('next-app');

  // Initialize Application Insights exporter with the Instrumentation Key
  const instrumentationKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY;
  const exporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter({ instrumentationKey });

  // Create a tracer provider and set the exporter
  const tracerProvider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    plugins: {
      // Add plugins here if needed
    },
  });

  tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));
  tracerProvider.register();
}
```

- Use `AzureMonitorTraceExporter` instead of `AzureMonitorBaseExporter` if it does not work.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing the information. I still cant able to get the logs in app insights. Also the in the instumentation.ts AzureMonitorBaseExporter started errored out saying Cannot create an instance of an abstract class. Also if possible can u provide the github code for the above.

Comment: the issue is how to use it inside the pages. I believe you showed how to define them. But how to use them inside the pages. Like I want to get the details of which page I have visited those information.

Comment: You can use OpenTelemetry to trace your page transitions. To do this, you can create custom spans or add attributes to spans to identify the pages you visit.

Comment: Found an easier way to by using `@vercel/otel`
https://maxwellweru.com/blog/2024/03/nextjs-opentelemetry-with-azure-monitor